# Powershell COM objects

Tags: com, powershell, outlook

I am attempting to get calendar items from a shared calendar via Powershell with the following code:

```
$outlook = new-object -ComObject Outlook.application
$session = $outlook.Session
$session.Logon("Outlook")
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient("John Smith")
$theirCalendar = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($recipient, "olFolderCalendar")
```

but I am getting a type mismatch error:

> Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.__ComObject", for "GetSharedDefaultFolder" to type "Microsoft.Office.I
>   nterop.Outlook.Recipient": "Cannot convert the "System.__ComObject" value of type "System.__ComObject#{00063045-0000-00
>   00-c000-000000000046}" to type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient"."
>   At line:1 char:34
>   + $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder <<<< ($recipient, "olFolderCalendar")
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

I've tried directly casting $recipient to a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient`, which doesn't work, and I have also tried the `invoke-method()` procedure well documented here: http://www.mcleod.co.uk/scotty/powershell/COMinterop.htm

It seems like the latter should work, but it doesn't appear to have provisions for the multiple parameters that `GetSharedDefaultFolder()` requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here: http://cjoprey.blog.com/2010/03/09/getting-another-users-outlook-folder/

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

$class = @”
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;public class MyOL
{
    public MAPIFolder GetCalendar(string userName)
    {
        Application oOutlook = new Application();
        NameSpace oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(userName);
        MAPIFolder calendar = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        return calendar;
    }
}
“@

Add-Type $class -ReferencedAssemblies Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

Comment: What's about Outlook when used with multiple smtp and Exchange accounts ?

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to get this working using the InvokeMember method of System.__ComObject. In order to pass multiple parameters to the method, simply enclose them in parentheses.

An example of the line of code is shown here:

PS C:> $usercontacts=[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("GetSharedDefaultFolder" [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$mapi,($user,10))

$user is the recipient object previously set up.
$mapi is the MAPI namespace object (also set up previously).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `olFolderCalendar` with the number `9`.
COM objects need the actual values. They cannot convert clear text names to constant values.

Comment: The error deals with the recipient object, not the folder object.

Comment: [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderCalendar should also work